# Getting fatal error when doing things with extension

Tags: api, extension, error

Whenever Im doing anything with extensions Im getting this error

```
CiviCRM_API3_Exception: "API error: on OptionValue.getsingle"

#0 /home/lgsecrmo/hub.littlegate.org.uk/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Admin/Form/Extensions.php(189): civicrm_api3("Extension", "enable", (Array:2))
#1 /home/lgsecrmo/hub.littlegate.org.uk/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Form.php(527): CRM_Admin_Form_Extensions->postProcess()
#2 /home/lgsecrmo/hub.littlegate.org.uk/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/StateMachine.php(144): CRM_Core_Form->mainProcess()
#3 /home/lgsecrmo/hub.littlegate.org.uk/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/QuickForm/Action/Next.php(43): CRM_Core_StateMachine->perform(Object(CRM_Admin_Form_Extensions), "next", "Next")
#4 /home/lgsecrmo/hub.littlegate.org.uk/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/HTML/QuickForm/Controller.php(203): CRM_Core_QuickForm_Action_Next->perform(Object(CRM_Admin_Form_Extensions), "next")
#5 /home/lgsecrmo/hub.littlegate.org.uk/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/HTML/QuickForm/Page.php(103): HTML_QuickForm_Controller->handle(Object(CRM_Admin_Form_Extensions), "next")
#6 /home/lgsecrmo/hub.littlegate.org.uk/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Controller.php(352): HTML_QuickForm_Page->handle("next")
#7 /home/lgsecrmo/hub.littlegate.org.uk/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Page/Basic.php(395): CRM_Core_Controller->run()
#8 /home/lgsecrmo/hub.littlegate.org.uk/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Page/Basic.php(140): CRM_Core_Page_Basic->edit(32, NULL)
#9 /home/lgsecrmo/hub.littlegate.org.uk/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Admin/Page/Extensions.php(105): CRM_Core_Page_Basic->run()
#10 /home/lgsecrmo/hub.littlegate.org.uk/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(313): CRM_Admin_Page_Extensions->run((Array:3), NULL)
#11 /home/lgsecrmo/hub.littlegate.org.uk/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(69): CRM_Core_Invoke::runItem((Array:15))
#12 /home/lgsecrmo/hub.littlegate.org.uk/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(36): CRM_Core_Invoke::_invoke((Array:3))
#13 /home/lgsecrmo/hub.littlegate.org.uk/sites/all/modules/civicrm/drupal/civicrm.module(458): CRM_Core_Invoke::invoke((Array:3))
#14 /home/lgsecrmo/hub.littlegate.org.uk/includes/menu.inc(527): civicrm_invoke("admin", "extensions")
#15 /home/lgsecrmo/hub.littlegate.org.uk/index.php(21): menu_execute_active_handler()
#16 {main}
```

I'm using latest Drupal and CiviCRM 5.41

Can anyone throw some light on this?

Comment: How are you enabling ext via UI or commandline?.

Comment: Im adding via the UI...hadn't though about the command line. I'll give it a go

Answer (score 0):

For these type of errors that don't make lots of sense, i would check the following.

-Memory exhaustion (increase it via php.ini and restart your webserver then try).

-Also, you can try the CV commandline utility and run it with verbose to see more errors (cv -vv ext:enable extention-name)